# unexpected shutdowns under GPU load, but GPU doesn't *appear* to be overheating

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power, shutdown, gpu

**Hi there! I really hope someone can help trouble shoot this!**

I'm getting unexpected shutdowns when GPu is under load. It has happened before (just last month), and it seemed to be fixed previously by repasting the GPU. However then the temp was running quite high, this time its executing a shutdown at around 70 degrees C which is well within normal range for the GPU. i redid the paste just in case, but its still shutting down during a test of The Valley.

I tried removing the GPU, and running valley using the onboard graphics and no problem, but I dont know whether that proves its a problem in the external GPU, or something else stressed by the GPU's presence.

last month I did the following 
"I ran memtest overnight and no faults with the ram sticks

I've tried monitoring voltage and at idle i get these results:

vcore: 0.8
12=12.24
5=5.07
3.3=3.344
vaxg=0.012
vrin=1.76

I ran prime 95 and voltage didn't move much at all and no failures"

Note: I don't have access to another GPU to test with, and I can't "buy one and return it" as suggested in another forum as I'm aware this goes against all sale conditions at the places I could get another card from and I cant afford to be stuck with another card I cant return.

Spec: 
my PSU is a :XFX - XTR 650W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply

case is a ENTHOO PRO TEMPERED GLASS

CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-4690 CPU @ 3.50GHz

Cooler: Cooler Master - Hyper 212 EVO 82.9 CFM Sleeve Bearing CPU Cooler

GPU: R9 380

MB: Gigabyte - GA-H97M-D3H

Ram: Corsair - Vengeance LP 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3-1600 Memory

boot drive: SanDisk - SSD PLUS 480GB 2.5" Solid State Drive

*EDIT* So It seems I just got paid, so a sub-question is now, would and RX 580 be compatible with my setup, and what would be a suitable PSU to get as a replacement please?

Answer (score 1):

Your PSU should be enough for what you have, but for the symptons you described it can be a PSU failure aswell (integrated GPU consumes much less power than R9 380, thats why it can seem your dedicated GPU is broken under this assumption). Capacitor's aging can cause a PSU to not be able to give its rated power after years of use, or maybe it is another problem with the same consequences.

Voltage at idle is usually not a reliable indicator of a PSU failing. Even under load, it will not be either, because a sudden drop of any voltage will force a shutdown almost instantly, before your software can register it and even less you see it.

Some software, like OCCT, has a PSU checking function (that is just prime95-like load for the CPU, plus furmark for the GPU, forcing a really high power consumption).

In case this is not the problem... well, the main culprit seems to be the card. Even when not overheating, it can fail. For example, it might be that a solder of the GPU chip is failing intermitently, and you just happened to apply a bit more pressure when you swapped the thermal paste (just a wild guess).

Sadly there is no workarround to completely discard the card except testing another one (with similar power consumtpion if possible). If you can't borrow one from a friend either, I would try to contact the manufacturer, even if it is out of warranty, to ask for a repair quote.

Comment: thanks for your answer. running anything that stressed GPU is causing a crash atm, so if I ran OCCT without the GPu connected, would that still be able to spot if the problem is the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Given your restriction on swapping the GPU, perhaps look at your CPU cooling solution as a possible culprit (or down-clock/disable TurboBoost, to see the effect).

The CPU gets stressed as well during Valley, but doesn't with memtest, and Prime 95 may be exercising a different part of the CPU.

Comment: thankyou! ill turn off turboboost in the bios and try valley again. ill get back with CPU temps from Hwin if/when it does another shutdown

Comment: ive got 43C on the cpu at point of crash. weirdly, this time when i ran valley it crashed before the visuals even apeared